# Detect touch on EditText, but not interrupt it?

Tags: android

I need to know when the user touches/taps/clicks the edittext in my activity.

How can I do this without interrupting the events, so the keypad still displays properly?

(And I need to know about it before the OS displays the keypad...if possible)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
txtEdit.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {                                                       
         // your code here....
         getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);                
         return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, although I didn't need the line above 'return false;' as the keypad appeared automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

...


}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because it can be difficult for the original poster (or future readers) to understand the logic behind them. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by attaching an [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) to your EditText. If you're concerned about blocking the UI thread in your OnClickListener, you can spawn a new Thread and do your work in there - though, if you do that, there's no guarantee the work will be done before the keypad shows up.

Comment: If I attached a new onFocusChangeListener, it interrupts the keypad, and it has to be pressed twice to show it.  When I override, is there a way to call super or something?  Maybe I'm reaching...

Comment: OK. Try looking at this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403632/android-show-soft-keyboard-automatically-when-focus-is-on-an-edittext

Comment: Actually, that was the example I was following.  I also tried getting the activity window and setSoftInputMode, but it always takes 2 taps to reveal the keypad.

Answer (score 0):

**Less verbosity**

The same [Mathias Conradt's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3389960/4744263) approach, but using kotlin:

```
txtEdit.setOnTouchListener({ view, motionEvent ->
    // your code here....
    false
})
```

This line `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);` is unnecessary since the keyboard shown when you tap the editText view.

Answer (score 0):

`OnTouchListener` was getting called twice for me (on *Pixel 2* running *Pie*). So I used 
`OnFocusChangeListener` instead:

```
txtEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Focused Now!");
                }
            }
        });
```