# when using AlertDialog.Builder with EditText, the Soft Keyboard doesn't pop

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I am using **AlertDialog.Builder** in order to create an input box, with EditText as the input method.

Unfortunately, the Soft Keyboard doesn't pop, although the **EditText** is in focus, unless you explicitly touch it again.

Is there a way to force it to pop?

I've tried the following, **after the (AlertDialog.Builder).show();** but for no avail.

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.showSoftInput(input, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

Anyone can help?

Thanks!!

Comment: please format your source code.

Comment: Then I upvote you as well :) I had the same problem search for multiple hours and the last answer from grine4ka works great

Answer (score 232):

I've made such a thing

```
AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);//....
AlertDialog dialog = b.create();

dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

dialog.show();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've searched for a while now and this is the way you want to go. All the `OnFocusChangeListener` approaches seem to much to me and cause trouble.
You have to create the `AlertDialog` from the `AlertDialog.Builder`!

Comment: Is this one really a solution? This just forces the keyboard to show, regardless if there is an input field or not, regardsless if the input field has focus or not, right? =)

Comment: @Ted you're right this one is not the real solution, but it works.i've tried to do such thing if there is no edittext in dialog, and soft keyboard didn't appear.

Comment: I actually manage to "solve it" (workaround). I use the setOnFocusChangeListener for the EditText, and in onFocusChange if check if it has focus (the "hasFocus" var) and if so, I do getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);

Comment: `SOFT_INPUT_STATE_UNCHANGED` also works if your keyboard is already visible before dialogue pops up.

Comment: oh ya.  thanks, i appreciate it enough to write 15 extra chars to make this comment validate..

Comment: I had the opposite requirement. The keyboard should NOT popup. I used the same solution, but with LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN. Thanks.

Comment: Why didnt mark this answer as correct? It's works for me thank, you save my time.

Comment: Note: For this to work, you need to place the `setSoftInputMode` line _before_ `dialog.show()` or it won't work. +1 for the simple correct solution btw

Comment: if it will not work, add line ' edittext.requestFocus()', it works for me

Comment: just a mention to use dialog.show() instead of  builder.show() otherwise it doesn't work

Answer (score 31):

I've managed to solve it like this:

```
Dialog = builder.create();
Dialog.show();
Dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE  | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
Dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Please be aware that calling `dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode()` **after** `dialog.show()` on Android 4-8 has a nasty side effect: dialog remains on screen after configuration changes, still tied to already destroyed Activity/Fragment.

Answer (score 25):

I found out that the same code works properly on Tablet, the keyboard does pop up, but on Phone it doesn't, so researching further, seems to point to the "adjust" option.

I am using this, feels much cleaner.

```
AlertDialog d = builder.create();
d.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
d.show();
```

Comment: Thanks. This is must better than using `SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE`. As `SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE` is going to block the UI components of dialog, where `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE` able to resize and "push up" the dialog.

Answer (score 14):

In my case the only way I was able to show the keyboard when the Dialog was shown was by adding to my `DialogFragment`:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getDialog().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
    getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    myEditText.requestFocus();
}
```

Note the **SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE** instead of *SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE*.
From documentation:

```
// Visibility state for softInputMode: please always make the soft input 
// area visible when this window receives input focus.
int SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE;
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me and I had tried LOADS of them. Mine was a dialogfragment build from alertdialog builder. The important bit seemed to be placing the above code in the onResume(). Anywhere else it just didn't work!

Comment: This solution works very well. The solution is for a dialog fragment but it worked well with an AlertDialog and I think it works for any kind of dialog. Just put those three line after calling the `show()` method of `AlertDialog`, then request focus for your input view.

Answer (score 7):

When you call `showDialog()` to show a Dialog created using `AlertDialog` in `onCreateDialog()`

You should put the code in `onPrepareDialog()`:

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog (int id, Dialog dialog, Bundle args)
{
    TextView editText=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R....);

    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
         if (hasFocus) {
            dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
         }
       }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A much better solution is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9118027/1208581).

```
dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(
         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
        |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
```

No workaround. `EditText` behaves as expected.

Comment: This one worked for me, the other solution were bringing the focus but keybord was not displayed.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the SoftInputMode wasn't getting displayed when I set it which was before showing the dialog (after creating it). The below code worked for me where I set the SoftInputMode after showing the dialog.

Kotlin:

```kotlin
val dialog = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context) // Other builder code
                .create()
dialog.show()
dialog.window?.apply { // After the window is created, get the SoftInputMode
    clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE)
    clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM)
    setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE)
}
```

Java:

```java
AlertDialog dialog = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(getContext()) // Other builder code
                .create();
dialog.show();
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
if(window != null){ // After the window is created, get the SoftInputMode
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
    window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
}
```

I hope this helps anyone who was having the same problem as me.

Answer (score 2):

```
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
    window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

This was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403632/android-show-soft-keyboard-automatically-when-focus-is-on-an-edittext) already. Using an OnFocusChangeListener worked for me.

Comment: The question asks how to set the soft input mode for an AlertDialog.Builder object, however the thread you refer to gives an example using an AlertDialog object. If I try to use the suggested code (using alert.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(...) within OnFocusChangeListener) Eclipse objects that the method getWindow() is not defined for the type AlertDialog.Builder. Can you help me fix this, please?

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when EditText is added after AlertDialog.onCreate is called.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AlertDialog.Builder

> The AlertDialog class takes care of automatically setting
> android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM for you
> based on whether any views in the dialog return true from
> View.onCheckIsTextEditor().

You need to clear the FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM flag.

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
```

Because AlertDialog.show is called in the DialogFragment.onStart, you can insert the code in the DialogFragment.onStart.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getDialog().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
}
```

Or you can use the Dialog.setOnShowListener if you do not use a DialogFragment.

```
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
        getDialog().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its working for me

If you want to display soft keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.showSoftInput(input.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

And if you want to hide the it:

```
  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(input.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

final AlertDialog dialog = alert.show();
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: It's better to include some context/explanation with code as this makes the answer more useful for the OP and for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its working for me

```
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    if (window != null) { // After the window is created, get the SoftInputMode
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
        window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy and reliable solution to this, just put a hidden EditText on root of your dialog layout if you got a complex layout which an editable field isn't in root,

```
<!-- Just to trick AlertDialog to not hide soft keyboard -->
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

This is basically to trick [this part](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/8cb282ccdbb00687dbf253a4419ded0dfc786fb5/appcompat/appcompat/src/main/java/androidx/appcompat/app/AlertController.java#L208-L228) of compat/androidx.

I used to use `onResume` solution above but with that I couldn't use simpler API of `AlertDialog.Builder()` to remove the use of `AppCompatDialogFragment` but now I can simply use the easier API.