# Android - CheckBox gets unchecked on keyboard show up?

Tags: android

[image]

The content of the dialog is a `ListView`, here's the adapter :

```
public class MultiSelectionSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context ctx;
    private ArrayList<MultiSelectionItem> items;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public MultiSelectionSpinnerAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<MultiSelectionItem> items) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.items = items;
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final MultiSelectionItem item = items.get(position);

        CheckBox checkBox;
        if (item.isEditable()) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.editable_checkbox, parent, false);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editableCheckbox);

            EditText editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editableEditText);
            editText.setText(item.getEditableValue());
            editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    item.setEditableValue(s.toString());
                }
            });
        } else {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.multi_selection_checkbox, parent, false);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView;
        }
        checkBox.setText(item.getLabel());
        checkBox.setChecked(item.isSelected());
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                item.setIsSelected(isChecked);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return items.get(position).getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: What view is above EditText? ListView?

Comment: Obviously, Adapter is not saving the states ....

Comment: Post your adapter code.

Comment: Indeed I'm not saving states in the Adapter, how do I do that ?

Comment: *how do I do that ?* I would start from google search as similar questions were asked bazillion times

Comment: How can you create list view and load data to it?

Comment: Okay thanks. Your profile picture suits you well btw

Comment: Yeah, i know ... thats how i react on duplicate questions ...

Comment: Please see edit (if you want), as the problem isn't saving states, but something more complexe

Comment: You have to use notifydatasetchanged(); after checking checkBoxes.

Comment: @Mehdiway hmmm,you are saving the states ... could you add the whole `dialogBuilder` code ?  .... getView is not perfect(you are not reusing the views) but should works with normal listview ... so maybe the problem is how you pass `items` to dialog/dialogbuilder

Comment: @Selvin I haven't used a ViewHolder because there aren't a lot of items. See edit for full adapter code

Comment: this work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309250/checkbox-gets-unchecked-on-scroll-in-a-custom-listview . I hope help you

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by adding

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"
```

to the mainfest file.

Answer (score -1):

You could try the solution proposed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455235/when-using-alertdialog-builder-with-edittext-the-soft-keyboard-doesnt-pop).
Basically setting up the SoftInputMode; like this:
`dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);`