# Android - Programmatically opening the keyboard/requesting focus on an EditText inside an AlertDialog

Tags: android

I have an Android Application and there's a part where I show an AlertDialog. In that AlertDialog, I have an EditText which is pre-populated with a value from the prefs and the user can change this.

The code works just fine, however, in order to be more intuitive with the User Experience, what I want to do is that when the Alert Dialog pops up, the pre-populated value from the preferences is highlighted already and the keyboard is ready.

So far, I have done the input highlight just fine but I can't get the keyboard to pop up or make the request focus work programmatically. Here's my code:

```
private void showPrefixChangerDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Set Pipe Prefix");

    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    input.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    input.setText(pipePrefix);
    input.setSelection(0, 2);
    input.performClick();
    input.requestFocus();
    InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
    filters[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(2);
    input.setFilters(filters);

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(input, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);


    builder.setView(input);

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String finalInput = input.getText().toString();
            saveInputToPrefs(finalInput);
            tv.setText("Pipe Prefix is " + finalInput);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

As you can see, I tried using `performClick()`, `requestFocus()`, and `InputManager`, but all to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution [from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6759386/1374416)

```
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

    dialog.show();
```

I need to google better

Answer (score 0):

Try this ("input" is your EditText):

```
InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
in.showSoftInput(input, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: uh, I already have that in my code. kindly read the code in my question.

Comment: you must call this after "builder.show()", because the editText is not yet visible

Comment: still doesn't work even after placing it after `builder.show()`