# Keyboard is displaying under the dialog and dialog is not moving up

Tags: android

I am using Alert Dialog having RecyclerView with custom adapter.

Issue is : on opening dialog : keyboard comes under the dialog.[image]

I tried to implement :

```
AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
                alert.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
              //  alert.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);

                alert.show();
```

and showed keyboard in adapter class with this :

```
 inputHoursEt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (hasFocus) {
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
                    }
                }
            });
```

also tried in manifest file this for main activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

EDIT:

Complete code for dialog:

```
 private void openEnterResourceHoursDialog(int i, String selectedActivityId, String selectedActivityName) {
        loader.dismiss();
            Log.i(Constants.APP_NAME, "total resources : "+resourceListItems.size());
            if (resourceListItems.size()>0){
                final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                final View content = factory.inflate(R.layout.resource_dialog, null);

                RecyclerView detailsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) content.findViewById(R.id.resourceListRv);
                LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

                detailsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
                llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

                Button detailSubmitButton = (Button) content.findViewById(R.id.enterBtn);
                Button detailsCloseButton = (Button) content.findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);
                TextView activityNameTv = (TextView) content.findViewById(R.id.activityNameTv);

                activityNameTv.setText(selectedActivityName);

                ResourceListAdapter detailsAdapter = new ResourceListAdapter(getActivity(), resourceListItems);
                detailsRecyclerView.setAdapter(detailsAdapter);

                dialog.setView(content);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                final AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
                alert.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE  );
              //  alert.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);

                alert.show();
                detailsCloseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        alert.dismiss();
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.RESULT_HIDDEN,0);
                    }
                });

                detailSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        alert.dismiss();
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.RESULT_HIDDEN,0);
                    }
                });

            }else{
                utils.showShortToast(getActivity(),"There is no resource");
            }
        }
```

Comment: try adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"` into activity tag of your manifest file

Comment: no this is also not working.

Comment: try changing soft input mode set on alert dialog to WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE or WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE

Comment: alertDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE); try with this. @HeenaArora

Comment: SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE and SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE both did not worked :(

Comment: this is also not working

Comment: Just for clarification. You have alert dialog which has recyclerview inside recyclerview u have edittext and when u click on the edittext, edittext will  get focus then alertdialog is coming over the keyboard right?

Comment: yes exactly, and displaying  alert dialog is in Fragment

Comment: Can u post the complete alert dialog implementation?

Comment: @HeenaArora I'm not sure try this set imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT); in setOnFocusChangeListener and try?

Comment: @Raghavendra after trying this keyboard is not opening on edittext click
I Edited my post, for complete code of dialog. Please check!

Comment: @HeenaArora okay I was wrong it might not show keyboard. Just a hunch , it may be wrong too just comment inputHoursEt.setOnFocusChangeListener implementation for a while and test?

Comment: @HeenaArora Please don't post that much code in comments make it as update in original post.

Comment: i already added code for setOnFocusChangeListener there

Comment: @HeenaArora okay can u try by commenting the entire setOnFocusChangeListener implementation once?

Comment: no it is not working

Comment: @HeenaArora keyboard is not popping up?

Comment: yes it is not popping up

Comment: @HeenaArora pls check any of the solution in this link is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054662/displaying-soft-keyboard-whenever-alertdialog-builder-object-is-opened

Comment: no, it tried all other posts.

Comment: See this Link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/76074557/12272687