# How to adjust the dialog size when keyboard is open?

Tags: android, dialog, resize

What I am trying to do: 
The keyboard should show at bottom of the dialog.

Code:
I am extending the Dialog class.

```
  window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE)
        window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
```

What I have tried:

1. window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
2. window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)

[As I have studied here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410499/difference-between-adjustresize-and-adjustpan-in-android), SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE should work but I am not able to figure out why It is not working in my case?

[image: login Screen]

Comment: Post the full dialog class code..for better understanding

Comment: Right before your onCreate ending parenthesis, simply add this code:   this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);  and your Manifest to change as:   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"  in the among of the activity codes within.

Answer (score 8):

Add following property into your activity tag (AndroidManifest.xml)

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Also you need to add below code in OnCreate function (MainActivity.java)

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

This solved the problem and it worked perfectly fine on all resolution emulators and samsung devices. It did fail, though, on Google Nexus S device and I could see the same problem again of virtual keyboard hiding the EditTexts.

You can try below code to make dialog adjustable as per keyboard status.

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

**Note** -: If you are using Dialog instead of alert Dialog do the below changes.

Create one style file e.g. dialog.xml. Put below code into it.

```
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnchanged</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#22AAEA</item>
</style>
```

Now apply style to dialog.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this , R.style.dialog);
```

**NOTICE** that the attribute "parent" is "Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" like a activity's style. and the attribute "android:windowFullScreen" should be false.

Now, the dialog will be resized when the soft keyboard toggled.

Comment: Hey, I have tried to set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in the parent activity but result is same.

Comment: Did you tried below code which should be in OnCreate?

Comment: still not worked. I am using Dialog instead of alertDialog that would be an issue??

Comment: I have updated the code for dialog. Please try once.

Comment: Thanks @androidOnHigh

Comment: Welcome @SARATHV

Answer (score 0):

Recently **SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE** is **deprecated** in Java, so is better change it. Here, there is a way:

```
Theme_Material_Dialog_Presentation
```

in **Style** or **AlertDialog.Builder** such as:

```
val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this,
                        android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Presentation)
```