# Automatically open softkeyboard on AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-softkeyboard

I'm creating an `AlertDialog.Builder` at which I'm assigning a `EditText` to get an input.
When it opens the keyboard doesn't automatically shows up.
Here is my code:

```
private void AskForInput(int inputType, String title) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(title);

    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setInputType(inputType);
    builder.setView(input);

    builder.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            keyNumberValue = input.getText().toString() + "#";
            //TODO: do things...
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

I tried to solve using a suggestion I got from another post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054662/displaying-soft-keyboard-whenever-alertdialog-builder-object-is-opened):

```
AlertDialog alertToShow = builder.create();
alertToShow.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
alertToShow.show();
```

But still I have to tap on the `EditText` to open the keyboard.
Any idea?

Comment: You tried input.requestFocus() already?

Comment: Ok.That worked with `alertToShow`. I just get a warning on `setSoftInputMode` -> NullPointerException. Is not important but I don't like exceptions. Any way to get rid of it?

Comment: never senn this before, but isn't the case of check if alertToShow.getWindow() != null ? If it not works, post the entire warning if possible!

Comment: @Shermano right answer. I had to check.