# AlertDialog - Show soft keyboard with a custom class not working

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-softkeyboard

My issue is that my custom alertdialog class is not displaying the softkeyboard correctly. I am creating it using

```
SettingsDialog settingsDialog = new SettingsDialog(MainActivity.this);
settingsDialog.show();
```

And the softkeyboard is not displaying. I've followed other stackoverflow answers to displaying the keyboard ... [Show soft keyboard for dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258623/show-soft-keyboard-for-dialog)

and it works if I do not use a custom class

```
AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
mBuilder.setView(R.layout.alertdialog_settings);
AlertDialog alertDialog = mBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

[image]

However when using a custom AlertDialog class I can't seem to get the same outcome as the picture above

I have tried manually displaying the keyboard

```
SettingsDialog settingsDialog = new SettingsDialog(MainActivity.this);
settingsDialog.show();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if(imm != null){
   imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
}
```

[image]

However it shows the keyboard behind the alertdialog and doesn't give the same effect as AlertDialog Builder.

How can I display the softkeyboard using a Custom AlertDialog to have output as using AlertDialog Builder?

**Edit:**

I have also tried manually displaying it in the AlertDialog's onCreate Method

```
public class SettingsDialog extends AlertDialog {
     public SettingsDialog(@NonNull Context context, String subName) {
            super(context);
            this.mContext = context;
            this.mSubName = subName;

     }

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alertdialog_settings);

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
        mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if(imm != null){
          imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
        }

     }
}
```

However this still causes the keyboard to be displayed behind the alertDialog

Comment: Can you public SettingsDialog?

Comment: public SettingsDialog?

Comment: yes, full code class SettingsDialog

Comment: It's only a constructor and the onCreate method in Edit Above ^

Comment: SettingsDialog  extends Dialog ?

Comment: Extends AlertDialog

Comment: @davids. I hope it'll help you: https://medium.com/@JakobUlbrich/building-a-settings-screen-for-android-part-2-2ba63e2d7d1d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you do not need to extend the Alert Dialog class, what you can do is simply a your custom java which contain helper function create your custom dialog, so you will still have code abstraction and can add additional features with ease.

```
public class SettingsDialog  {

  private  AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = null;
  private  AlertDialog alertDialog = null;

 public SettingsDialog(@NonNull Context context, String subName) {
        this.mSubName = subName;
        this.mContext = context;
 }

 public show(){
    mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    mBuilder.setView(R.layout.someID);
    alertDialog = mBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
 }

 public void dismiss(){
    if(alertDialog == null) return;
    alertDialog.dismiss();
 }

 // can use interface to handle callbacks

}


// usage 

SettingsDialog sd = new SettingsDialog(this, "MATHS");
sd.show();
//sd.dismiss();
```

Comment: This also works :) I'd say this is even a better solution. Will mark yours as correct

Comment: @davids. always happy to help. but i like to know, when i will receive bounty ?

Comment: @AbhishekGarg..can you help me out here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59532667/particular-titlefetched-from-api-using-searchview

Comment: I think when the bounty is over tomorrow?

Comment: @Wini sure, let me look .

Comment: @davids. bounty is ending tomorrow ..none of the solution matched..

Comment: @Wini here is my answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59624771/9079028

Comment: @AbhishekGarg I didn't know I had to manually click the bounty button to give it to you. I thought it would automatically give you it lol

Answer (score 6):

I've tried many other methods but this one finally works.

```
SortByDialog sortByDialog = new SortByDialog(MainActivity.this);
sortByDialog.show();
sortByDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
```

Need to make sure the clearFlags is after the `.show()` for your custom AlertDialogClass

Comment: A million dollar solution :)

Answer (score -2):

Try to show the keyboard with some delay е.g. 100-200ms after the dialog create, or just try to request focus for the dialog's EditText using EditText.requestFocus() also with delay after the dialog create.