# Android: What is android.R.id.content used for?

Tags: android, android-resources

Anybody could explain the meaning of "android.R.id.content" ?

How is it being used ?

http://developer.android.com does not have any explanation.

> public static final int content
> Since: API Level 1
>
> Constant Value: 16908290 (0x01020002)

Comment: `android.R.id.content` gives you the root element of a view, without having to know its actual name/type/ID. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486034/android-how-to-get-root-view-from-current-activity

Comment: This is useful in fragment transactions like:
mFragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, myFragment);

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky An example app performs this kind of transaction in a conditional:`if(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content)==null) {fragmentManager.beginTransaction(android.R.id.content, list).add().commit();}` Can you tell which `View`'s root element is this?

Comment: @Zarah Are you sure your syntax is correct here and compilable?

Comment: What is the class of the layout associated with `android.R.id.content `?

Comment: @Sushant Since it (`android.R.id.content`) gives you the root element as Philipp Reichart points out, without having to know its actual name / **type** / ID, you can either do type checks to find out if it's a `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, etc.  Or you can just cast to `ViewGroup` if you just need the reference to the view.

Answer (score 118):

As [Philipp Reichart commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776768/android-what-is-android-r-id-content-used-for/12887919#comment9469885_7776768):

> `android.R.id.content` gives you the root element of a view, without having to know its actual name/type/ID. Check out [Get root view from current activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486034/android-how-to-get-root-view-from-current-activity)

In case anyone need, you can get this view with [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) by using `binding.root`

Comment: A practical example of it's use can be found in paragraph 2: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

Comment: "gives you the root element _of a view_, without having to know its actual name/type/ID" How does it know which view is it that we want the root element of.

Comment: In case anyone need, you can get this view with View Binding by using `binding.root`

Answer (score 28):

The `android.R.id.content` ID value indicates the `ViewGroup` of the entire content area of an `Activity`.

It can be used with `Fragment`:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, MyFragment.newInstance())
                .commit();
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

The code above will insert the `View` created by `Fragment` into the `ViewGroup` identified by `android.R.id.content`.

Answer (score 10):

Google designers develop Android UX with specific or recommended design guidelines.  The layout android.R.id.content defines a *linearlayout* with a few attributes Android believes are a good standard.

Thus loading a Fragment Manager's root view with android.R.id.content ensures these guidelines are implemented.

NOTE: This layout has set the attribute:  *android:addStatesFromChildren="true"* to allow child fragments to overwrite attributes in this rootview.

As of version 19, android.R.id.content is defined in a file:  auto_complete_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"
    android:divider="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_textfield"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="true">
```

Answer (score 2):

**From Fragment Example**

```
Snackbar.make(requireContext(), requireActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content), item.getCategoryName(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

android.R.id.content is very useful for when you need a view, for example:

**Show Snackbar:**

```
Snackbar.make(activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content), MESSAGE, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**Fragment transaction**

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, FragmnetTest.newInstance())
                .commit();
```