# Accepting Text input in Android without an EditText

Tags: android

I want to accept text input in android without using an EditText.  I am trying to create a drawing application (sorta) anyway, I need to accept text input on a zoomable view that I created.  Then I want to display the text where ever the user has indicated.  Displaying the text isn't the problem though, just accepting input.  I figured out how to show the soft keyboard but the okKey and okKeydown stuff doesn't appear to do what I need and appears more related to handling physical keyboards.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input text dialog Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903754/input-text-dialog-android)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of thoughts.

- Create a custom keyboard view and read values from onClick. You can get lots of keyboard examples(You just need the keyboard layout view to accept input on every click).
- Soft Keyboard comes up when it find an editable field. If you have managed to bring it up, for example by creating an invisible input field or dummy editable field, then you might have to use the same field to read the values that will be fed back by the keyboard.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I dont think I want or need to create a custom keyboard view unless I am just missing what that would do completely.  I don't want to make my own keyboard I want to get text input from the user via their normal input mechanism.  I got the keyboard to come up by just requesting it not by using a hidden box but I suppose I could try that so long as I could accept input it will solve my problem.

Comment: @Digital Power, You got it? I'm looking to get a text entry on my canvas without using edittext