# Trying to set text of EditText from DatePicker DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, datepicker, android-dialogfragment

I am simply trying to get the date from a datepicker dialog I created from one of the many android datepicker tutorials I found online. I seem to be going wrong somewhere in the actual retrieving of the text date once it is selected. I have a DatePickerFragment class, which is called from a CreateEvent fragment which is nested inside my MainActivity activity class. This is the DatePicker:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private EditText txtDate;
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        txtDate = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        txtDate.setText(day + " " + (month + 1) + " " + year);
    }
}
```

I get `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence) on a null object reference` when I actually try and set the date, which I understand means it can't actually find the edittext element in my create event fragment xml file.

How should I go about setting the text of this edittext element from `onDateSet` or do I have to change my approach?

I tried it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32731254/1326996) but to no avail.

Comment: txtDate = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.txtDate); is wrong, there is no edit text in datepicker, check my answer

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Are you trying to retrieve the actual date from the DatePicker and display it in an EditText or do you want to set it on the DatePicker ?

Comment: display it in an EditText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an **interface** to get the data from the `datepicker` to the caller `fragment`:

```
public interface DateListener {
    void passDate(String date);
}
```

Create a *member variable* called `mListener`:

```
private DateListener mListener;
```

Override the `onAttach` & `onDetach` `fragment` methods:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (DateListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement DateListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}
```

Next, implement this `interface` in the caller `fragment` and override the `passDate` method:

```
@Override
public void passDate(String date) {
    // Do something with 'date', yourEditText.setText(date) for the example
}
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: But there's no onCreateView in a DialogFragment?

Comment: There is. Override it. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: Okay but I also don't have a custom xml file for this dialogfragment. So R.layout.customdialog wouldn't apply

Comment: Use one. Otherwise you won't be able to access the EditText. (which requires a layout ?)

Comment: The EditText is located on the form in my create event fragment's layout file, not on the dateepicker

Comment: I know, and the DatePicker itself is located in the fragment's layout. Have you tried my solution ?

Comment: I have but it won't work because I have no custom datepicker layout.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this by below lines of code:

```
public class DatePickerDialogMy extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        DateSetting dateSetting=new DateSetting(getActivity());
        Calendar calendar= Calendar.getInstance();
        int year= calendar.get(calendar.YEAR);
        int month=calendar.get(calendar.MONTH);
        int day=calendar.get(calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        DatePickerDialog dialog;
        dialog=new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),dateSetting,year,month,day);
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Second Class:

```
        public class DateSetting implements android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
            Context context;
            public DateSetting(Context context){
                this.context=context;

            }
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int dateSetting, int dayOfMonth) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "selected date:" + dateSetting + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //        MainActivity.test.setText(String.valueOf(dateSetting));
                MyActivity.dobEditText.setText(dateSetting+"/"+dayOfMonth+ "/" + year);
            }
        }
```

**How to call:**

```
 DatePickerDialogMy datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialogMy();
                datePickerDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date_picker");
```