# ArrayList<String> getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, arraylist

I want to get an `ArrayList` from one `Fragment` to another, I use the `Intent`method, like this:

**Fragment where I want to get it from**

```
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("server_name_list", server_name_list);
```

If I debug this, I can see the new entry I did. But in the `Fragment` where I use `getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra` there is no new entry.
What did I wrong?

Here is the code from the `Fragment` where I use the method:

```
/* Server Name Spinner */
        ArrayList<String> server_name_list = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("server_name_list");

        if (server_name_list != null) {

            spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.server_spinner);
            ;
            ArrayAdapter<String> server_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, server_name_list);

            server_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(server_adapter);

            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                    selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

                    myWebView.loadUrl(selected);
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
```

**Edit: Whole code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AddServerFragment.Callback {

    static WebView myWebView;
    Fragment AddServerFragment, WebViewFragment;
    ArrayList<String> server_name_list;

    @Override
    public ArrayList<String> getArrayListFromActivity() {

        WebViewFragment frag = (WebViewFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("AddServerFragment");
        if (frag != null) {
            server_name_list = frag.getArrayListFromWebViewFragment();
        }
        return server_name_list;
    }

    /* Menu */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.webview:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, new WebViewFragment() {

                        })
                        .commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.add_server:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, new AddServerFragment() {

                        })
                        .commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_refresh:
                myWebView.reload();
                return true;
            default:
                return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (findViewById(R.id.container) != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }
            AddServerFragment = new Fragment();
            WebViewFragment = new Fragment();
        }
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, new WebViewFragment() {

                })
                .commit();
    }

    /*WebView Fragment*/
    public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {

        String selected;
        Spinner spinner;

        public WebViewFragment(){
        }

        private Callback callback;

        public interface Callback {
            public ArrayList<String> getArrayListFromActivity();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            callback = (Callback) activity;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview, container, false);

            /* WebView */
            myWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebC());
            WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();

            /* JavaScript Enable */
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            /* Server Name Spinner */

            ArrayList<String> server_name_list = callback.getArrayListFromActivity();

            if (server_name_list != null) {

                spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.server_spinner);
                ;
                ArrayAdapter<String> server_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, server_name_list);

                server_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner.setAdapter(server_adapter);

                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                        selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

                        myWebView.loadUrl(selected);
                    }

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
            }
            return view;
        }
    }

    /*Add Server Fragment*/
    public class AddServerFragment extends Fragment
            implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }

        public AddServerFragment(){
        }

        Button btn_back, btn_add;
        EditText server_ip, server_name;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_ip, container, false);

            server_ip = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_server_address);
            server_name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_server_name);

            btn_back = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
            btn_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.container, new WebViewFragment() {

                            })
                            .commit();
                }
            });

            btn_add = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
            btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String new_server_ip = null, new_server_name = null;

                    ArrayList<String> server_name_list = new ArrayList<>();
                    ArrayList<String> server_ip_list = new ArrayList<>();

                    new_server_ip = server_ip.getText().toString();
                    server_ip_list.add(new_server_ip);

                    new_server_name = server_name.getText().toString();
                    server_name_list.add(new_server_name);
                }
            });

            return view;
        }
    }

    /* WebView Client */
    public class WebC extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to pass data from one fragment to another, you need to do it via the holder activity.

Comment: Ok, thanks dude. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your ArrayList as a member variable of your container activity :

```
private ArrayList<String> server_name_list;
```

Add a getter:

```
public ArrayList<String> getArrayList() {
    return server_name_list;
}
```

And in your fragments, you access it this way: (supposing that the container activity's name is **MainActivity**)

```
ArrayList<String> arraylist = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getArrayList();
```

Comment: Not the recommended technique due to [tight coupling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565661/fragment-2-fragment-communicating). An `interface` or `EventBus` is always the better option, even if it takes a bit more boilerplate.

Comment: In deed. Let's just take it easy on the guy. The other way is pretty complicated for him now, I suppose. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33708631/trying-to-set-text-of-edittext-from-datepicker-dialogfragment/33708667#33708667

Comment: Haha yes, I'm a noob at this, first I only want to get it work. So you say I should try the link in your answere?

Comment: You can try both ways. Though I highly recommend you use the one listed here, not in the link. (for the moment)

Comment: Ok, I try it to put the right code fragments in my code. If I have problems, I edit my question with the new code I put in

Comment: Let me know how it ends

Comment: 2 questions: Where do I put `private ArrayList<String> server_name_list;` in? In the `Fragment` where I want to get the new `server_name_list`?
The second question is the same with `public ArrayList<String> getArrayList() {
    return server_name_list;
}`

Comment: @JDev Fair enough - I've put up an answer that shows the `interface` technique if @Sorrow91 wants to take a look alongside yours :)

Answer (score 2):

**JDev**'s answer is correct in so far as it will give you the result you want with the smallest amount of code. It is also, conceptually, the easiest method to understand. However, the technique recommended by Android Developers for a `Fragment` to communicate with its hosting `Activity` is via an `interface`.

It is worth learning this technique IMO, even if you are unfamiliar with `interface`s in Java and Android. This is because interfaces are used in all but the most basic of projects, and they underpin many recommended design patterns, so you can be sure they will turn up sooner or later :)

Here is how you would solve your problem with an `interface`:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private Callback callback;

    public interface Callback {
        public ArrayList<String> getArrayListFromActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        callback = (Callback) activity; 
        //NB: The above will throw ClassCastException if your Activity
        //Does not implement MyFragment.Callback
    }

    //Later in your code, whenever you want to grab the ArrayList<String> from your Activity:
    ArrayList<String> arrList = callback.getArrayListFromActivity();
```

Inside `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyFragment.Callback {

    ArrayList<String> arrayList;

    @Override
    public ArrayList<String> getArrayListFromActivity() {

        //If the ArrayList is in your Activity, then use:
        return arrayList;

        //If the ArrayList is in another Fragment, then use:
        FragmentTwo frag = (FragmentTwo) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag_of_fragment_two");
        if (frag != null) {
            arrayList = frag.getArrayListFromFragmentTwo();
            return arrayList;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey dude, I edit my question, with the edited code. But there is something from and I can't find out what I have to do. Can you take a look if you have time? Tanks :)

Comment: @Sorrow91 Hey Sorrow. It may be worth opening a new question if you're having a problem setting up your interface, simply because it's a separate topic and probably too long to debug via comments. Specify the problem you are having (i.e. you're getting the incorrect data, you're getting an error message), specify what it is you're trying to do, any debugging steps you've tried with and that haven't worked, a link to this answer and add in the code you feel is relevant,along with any `LogCat` output for error messages. Comment in a link when done and I can take a look!

Comment: Ok thank you, I will open a new question. But maby tomorrow, now I don't have the time. Have a good night dude

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725356/passing-an-arraylist-via-interface-between-2-fragments) here is my new question

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> server_name_list;//declare variable

... void onCreate(...)
{
 .
 .
 .
 server_name_list = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("server_name_list");//assign value
}
```

try this.if doesn't work try

intent.putExtra("server_name_list", server_name_list);
instead of 
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("server_name_list", server_name_list);

Comment: Thanks for your answere. 
I put `ArrayList<String> server_name_list;` over my `protected void onCreate(...)` and the `server_name_list = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("server_name_list");` before my `if (server_name_list != null)` but it doesnt work.

Comment: have you changed putStringArrayExtra(..) to putExtra(..) look my answer i edited it.

Comment: Yes I did, should I do the same with getStringArrayExtra to getExtra?

Answer (score -1):

you can simply pass any parameter through static instance of that fragment.
intent is normally used to transfer data among activities not fragments

```
 DestinationFragment Frag = DestinationFragment.getInstance(yourArrayList);

 FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            if (shouldAddToBackStack)
                ft.addToBackStack(tag);
            else {
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            }
            ft.replace(R.id.container, Frag, tag)
                    .commit();
            getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

in your DestinationFragment

```
public static DestinationFragment getInstance(ArrayList yourArrayList){
        DestinationFragment fragment=new DestinationFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(args, yourArrayList);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

Comment: then what is your actual problem ?