# Passing an ArrayList via interface between 2 fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, interface

Hey I try to pass an `ArrayList` with the `Interface` method between two `Fragments` in one activity.
The logcat says there are no errors, but the item I added the `ArrayList`in the one `Fragment` is not shown in my `Spinner` in the other `Fragment`.
I will post my whole code, so if you see my problem, it would be nice if you explain me the solution. Thanks in advance.

**MainActivity.java**

```
 package de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Callback {

    static WebView myWebView;
    Fragment AddServerFragment, WebViewFragment;
    ArrayList<String> server_name_list;

    @Override
    public ArrayList<String> getArrayListFromActivity() {

        WebViewFragment frag = (WebViewFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("AddServerFragment");
        if (frag != null) {
            server_name_list = frag.getArrayListFromActivity();
        }
        return server_name_list;
    }

    /* Menu */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.webview:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, new WebViewFragment() {

                        })
                        .commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.add_server:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, new AddServerFragment() {

                        })
                        .commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_refresh:
                myWebView.reload();
                return true;
            default:
                return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (findViewById(R.id.container) != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }
            AddServerFragment = new Fragment();
            WebViewFragment = new Fragment();
        }
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, new WebViewFragment() {

                })
                .commit();
    }

    /*WebView Fragment*/
    public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {

        String selected;
        Spinner spinner;

        public WebViewFragment(){
        }

        private Callback callback;


        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            callback = (Callback) activity;}

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview, container, false);

            /* WebView */
            myWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebC());
            WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();

            /* JavaScript Enable */
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            /* Server Name Spinner */

            ArrayList<String> server_name_list = callback.getArrayListFromActivity();

            if (server_name_list != null) {

                spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.server_spinner);
                ;
                ArrayAdapter<String> server_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, server_name_list);

                server_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner.setAdapter(server_adapter);

                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                        selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

                        myWebView.loadUrl(selected);
                    }

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
            }
            return view;
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getArrayListFromActivity() {
            return server_name_list;
        }
    }

    /*Add Server Fragment*/
    public class AddServerFragment extends Fragment
            implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }

        public AddServerFragment(){
        }

        Button btn_back, btn_add;
        EditText server_ip, server_name;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_ip, container, false);

            server_ip = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_server_address);
            server_name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_server_name);

            btn_back = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
            btn_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.container, new WebViewFragment() {

                            })
                            .commit();
                }
            });

            btn_add = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
            btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String new_server_ip = null, new_server_name = null;

                    ArrayList<String> server_name_list = new ArrayList<>();
                    ArrayList<String> server_ip_list = new ArrayList<>();

                    new_server_ip = server_ip.getText().toString();
                    server_ip_list.add(new_server_ip);

                    new_server_name = server_name.getText().toString();
                    server_name_list.add(new_server_name);
                }
            });

            return view;
        }
    }

    /* WebView Client */
    public class WebC extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

        }
    }
}
```

**Callback.java**

```
 package de.kwietzorek.fulcrumwebview;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface Callback {
        ArrayList<String> getArrayListFromActivity();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you're adding something into the ArrayList that is used by some Adapter (in your case by adapter for the spinner) you have to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() on it. So you have to "tell" the WebViewFragment that it needs to refresh (call notifyDataSetChanged() on adapter) it's content each time you're adding something to ArrayList in your second fragment

Comment: Thanks for your answere, I added `server_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` under `spinner.setAdapter(server_adapter);`
But nothing changed.

Comment: Firstly, you have to call it each time you're adding something inside you AddServerFragment not only inside OnCreateView method()
Secondly, your code is more buggy, you're returning an ArrayList with your servers in first fragment shouldn't it be the second one, the one where you're adding servers?

Comment: I have a startview, the `WebViewFragment`. But if I want to add a new server ip, I want to go on the `AddServerFragment` and add the server which I want to show in the `Spinner`

Comment: So I must add `
                server_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` under `new_server_name = server_name.getText().toString();
                    server_name_list.add(new_server_name);`
I added the `Adapter` `server_adapter` but it says that I have to add the method for my `.notifyDataSetChanged();`. Must I add the whole adapter new?

Comment: Just below those lines: "new_server_name = server_name.getText().toString();
                    server_name_list.add(new_server_name);" you have to notify your adapter, but it can't be new adapter it have to be the old one that you're using inside your WebViewFragment

Comment: I added `server_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` under `new_server_name = server_name.getText().toString(); server_name_list.add(new_server_name);` but my app crashs, and in the logcat stand: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference`

Comment: I think you don't know basisc of java to be honest, but if you're using server_adpter in your second fragment before this: "new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, server_name_list);" than you will get that exception the best way I think would be to create this adapter inside your activity onCreate method and use it beetween those two fragments not by using interface but just to declare this adapter as your actvity variable