# Allow User to edit button text on long click in Android

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, onlongclicklistener

I want to allow the App users to change the Button text in Android. When User clicks Button, it should do something but when he/she LongClicks the button, an edittext should pop-up & whatever user types into it should get saved as Button Text.
       So far I have completed following thing.

```
btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
etLabel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);

btn1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // How to pop-up edittext from here 
                // to allow user change Button name
                btn1.setText(name);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                // do something else here
                break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: google it you will find your answer, please try to research first before posting your question. you will find several posts answering your question.

Comment: what issue you are facing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
public class SOdemoAcitvity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btn;
private EditText edit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.so_demo);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_demo);
    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

    btn.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            showDialog(edit.getText().toString());

            return true;
        }


    });
}

private void showDialog(String str) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("input text");
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null);
    final EditText edit_dialog = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_dialog);
    edit_dialog.setText(str);
    builder.setView(view);
    builder.setNegativeButton("cancel",null);
    builder.setPositiveButton("confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    btn.setText(edit_dialog.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
}
```

**dialog_view xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
android:id="@+id/edit_dialog"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

and then

[image]

Comment: Hi Cgx. Tried your solution but on longClick nothing happens

Comment: One more thing. When I save the text, its a temporary change. I want to save it permanently until I change it again through LongClick. How this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a input dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903754/input-text-dialog-android) to get a text from user

```
btn1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                builder.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

and set the text of btn1 like below:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       btn1.setText(input.getText().toString());
    }
});
```