# WebChromeClient not displaying the "message" parameter to the onJsPrompt function

Tags: android, android-webview, webchromeclient

I want my WebView to display a prompt just like a web browser would.

From other answers addressing alert(), I found that I must do something like this in my Java code:

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
// Next line was added 
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

This works, and the prompt pops up, but instead of displaying the message I pass to `prompt()`, it instead says:

```
The page at "https:..." says:
```

In javascript my call looks like this:

```
prompt("Test")
```

So I would expect the prompt to say "Test".

This totally breaks the immersion of the WebView being embedded in an app.  How do I get the WebChromeClient to display the text I actually pass?

Comment: Can you please post the code snippet you tried?

Comment: @Asama I have expanded the java code to the whole relevant snippet, and have added my prompt call from javascript

Comment: Check my answer... You need to create dialog to set custom title...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an `AlertDialog` in `onJsPrompt` under `WebChromeClient` and attach an EditText as its view like so:

```
@Override boolean onJsPrompt (WebView view, String url, String message, String defaultValue, JsPromptResult result) { 
    final EditText input = new EditText(main);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    input.setText(defaultValue);
    new AlertDialog.Builder(myApp) 
      .setTitle("App Titler")
      .setView(input)
      .setMessage(message)
      .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           result.confirm(input.getText().toString()); 
         } 
       })
      .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           result.cancel(); 
         }
       })
     .create()
     .show();
     return true;
 }
```

Comment: I am interested in onJSPrompt (prompt), not onJSConfirm (alert)

Comment: I assume what I actually need is something similar, but instead of an AlertDialog I need something that actually fetches and returns text, but I'm not seeing a direct analog

Comment: Something like the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903754/input-text-dialog-android) ... appears I still need an AlertDialog with a custom view

Comment: You may try replacing onJsConfirm with onPrompt code and leave alertdialog as is... These are similar.

Comment: Edited it to add a few lines that made the text entry part work. Thanks!

Comment: Edited to add "setOnCancelListener" otherwise the site will stay inresponsive bc result.cancel() was not called