# How to create dialog which have textview in Android?

Tags: android, textview, android-alertdialog

I am trying to create a dialog box with `Textview`  in android like:

[image: Image]]

For creating the `Textview`, I am using following function `object.settype(textviewobject)` but there is no success.

Comment: Create a custom dialog: https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Comment: you can customize the alert dialog by extending the DialogFragment class.http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2013/09/custom-dialogfragmnet-example-in-android.html

Comment: what is your requirement

Comment: my requirement is that i apply login with Facebook functionality in my app it is done successfully then next step is that i want to fetch Facebook logged in user details like first name , last name, email in dialog textview control . if you know that how to fetch detail and display in dialog textview then please and me @SaurabhPadwekar thank you in advance..

Comment: You can use fragment dialog if your data is more.

Comment: i apply your solution @RohitSharma , it's worked.. I designed my App UI.Thanks

Comment: But i don't know how to fetch Facebook detail @SaurabhPadwekar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:-

```
    private void fn_showAlertDialog() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this)
            .setTitle("Title of your dialog")
            .setMessage("Text that you want to show.")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //do your task
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //do your task
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
            TextView text1 = 
                      (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            Button proceed =
            (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.button);

            proceed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });

            dialog.show();
```

dialog.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout   
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical" 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text1"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Proceed"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


 </RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use alertdialog like this, and create another layout for dialog:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                @SuppressLint("InflateParams") final View alertlayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notif_msg_dialog, null);

                TextView text_main=(TextView)alertlayout.findViewById(R.id.notif_msg);
                text_main.setText("YOUR TEXT");


                builder.setView(alertlayout);
                packsizeDialog=builder.create();
                packsizeDialog.show();
```

Here, notif_msg_dialog.xml is layout which has textview

Answer (score 0):

Just use AlertDialog.Builder and put your text in setMessage it will display

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setMessage("your text");
        builder.create();
        builder.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get help from following  post `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903754/input-text-dialog-android`