# How to Append website URL with Reference Number?

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development. I am trying to build an app to show electricity bills in an android app only by entering the reference numbers.Like the below website. http://210.56.23.106:888/pescobill/. In this website when we enter for expample this reference number(03261120015490) it shows bill. 
What i am trying to get on my android app is that i don't want to show the whole website i want to show a custom dialog box for entering reference number and after pressing enter it directly open the bill in my app. 
Is there any solution for this?
Will be looking for your kind response. 
Thanks

Comment: try something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903754/input-text-dialog-android

Comment: @Blundell Thanks for the comment but this only shows the implementation of alertbox. But i want to open Bill image by entering reference number in alertbox.

Comment: Yes, you need to break it into steps. Step 1, do the alert dialog.  Stackoverflow is for specific problems, not for whole project solutions. So try step 1 first. Then see if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do this is by building an API to connect to your database :
to achieve that , you can do like that :

1. Specify the format of communication between the API and client(Android/iOS) like JSON witch is recommended
2. build and API witch is a programme that runs on your server side to read and write data to your database
3. consume these API from you android code by using REST http client library like Retrofit witch is recommended

like that you do not have to show your entire website and use the API to send the reference number and receive a response in JSON format or image data then display it in the way you like