# Input dialog doesn't take right value ,

Tags: java, android, dialog

I'm trying to make a spreadsheat, but I face a problem - I get a "reandom" result returned by the dialog box.

my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical">


  <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
    android:layout_marginVertical="30dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

 <TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#020202"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="1dp"
    android:layout_marginVertical="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleR"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="prod price"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="1dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="1dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleQ"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Quantité"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="0dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="1dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Totale"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="1dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="1dp"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="1dp"
    android:layout_marginVertical="0dp"
    android:background="#020202"
    android:baselineAligned="false"

    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/r5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="v 5 usd"

        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/q5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="0dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:maxLength="5"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="0"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="1dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""/>
    </TableRow>
     <TableRow
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginHorizontal="1dp"
     android:layout_marginVertical="0dp"
     android:background="#020202"

     >
     <TextView
         android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
         android:id="@+id/myprc"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:background="@android:color/white"
         android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
         android:layout_marginHorizontal="1dp"
         android:text="Pourcentage"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:onClick="onClick"
         ></TextView>

     <TextView
         android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
         android:id="@+id/prcc"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_marginHorizontal="0dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:autoText="false"
         android:background="@android:color/white"
         android:clickable="true"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:inputType="text"
         android:maxLength="2"
         android:maxLines="1"
         android:text="6%"></TextView>
     ><TextView
     android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
     android:id="@+id/prcT"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="25dp"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:background="@android:color/white"
     android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
     android:layout_marginHorizontal="1dp"
     ></TextView>
    </TableRow>

 </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

my java code:

```
package com.example.mcalc;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView myprc;
    EditText q5;
    TextView t5;
    TextView t50;
    TextView prcc;// cel
    TextView prcT;
    double prc1;
    DecimalFormat tst = new DecimalFormat(" #,0.00 '%'");
    EditText input;// dilog input


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabble);

        myprc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myprc);
        q5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.q5);
        t5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t5);
        t50 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t50);
        prcc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prcc) ;//cel
        prcT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prcT);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Pourcentage");
        builder.setMessage("Merci d entrer le %");
        input=new EditText(this);
        builder.setView(input);

        ////
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                prc1 = Double.parseDouble(input.getText().toString());
                String str;
                str= String.valueOf(((Double) prc1));
                prcc.setText(str+"%");
            }
        });

        final   AlertDialog ad = builder.create();
        //Click listener Pourcentage %
        myprc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ad.show();
            }
        });

        q5.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                double tq5;

                if ((q5.getText().length() == 0)) {
                    t5.setText("");
                } else {
                    tq5 = (Double.valueOf(q5.getText().toString())*5) - 
                          (Double.valueOf(q5.getText().toString())*5*prc1);
                    t5.setText(""+tq5);
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
        prcc.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                double prc;

                if ((prcc.getText().length() == 0)) {
                    prcT.setText("");
                } else {
                    prcT.setText("blabla");
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: video link https://youtu.be/bu-62pj102g

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903754/input-text-dialog-android