# How to open a text box in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

Essentially, I want to open an input text box when the app is first opened that prompts the user to input their userid. I don't need to verify the id, I simply need to store it as a string for a later task. How do I make a pop up window that disappears once the user has entered their id?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Input text dialog Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903754/input-text-dialog-android)

Answer (score 0):

These were helpful in learning how to make a popup window:

1. [PopupWindow documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)
2. [How To Create Pop Up Window In Android (YouTube video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxqgtEewdfo)
3. [Android Popup Window Example](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2016/01/android-popup-window-example.html)