# findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView() nullPointerException

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, rootview

Why does calling `findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView()` in onPause or onStop return NPE but not when I call it in onCreate?

Comment: My best guess-  in onPause and onStop you're unattached from the window that is holding you.

Comment: Try this two links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486034/get-root-view-from-current-activity http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776768/android-what-is-android-r-id-content-used-for

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code of `android.view.View.getRootView()`:

```
public View getRootView() {
        if (mAttachInfo != null) {
            final View v = mAttachInfo.mRootView;
            if (v != null) {
                return v;
            }
        }

        View parent = this;

        while (parent.mParent != null && parent.mParent instanceof View) {
            parent = (View) parent.mParent;
        }

        return parent;
    }
```

it at least return the view itself.

After I tried logging `findViewById(android.R.id.content)`, and `findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView()` in *onStop*, *onPause*, *onCreate*, *onResume*, it worked all fine. No NPE.

could you put your Activity code?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce this error on Android 4.2.2. You might be getting that *NullPointerException* from something else.
By the way, `findViewById(android.R.id.content)` returns the *rootview* so `getRootView()` is usually ineffective.