# Android Activity with two fragments: How to tell the system which FrameLayout I want to add my Fragment into?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-framelayout

Suppose a `FragmentActivity` is supposed to have two different `Fragment`s (side by side where the right one is twice the width of the left one), which will be added dynamically.

How do we tell the system which `Fragment` goes into which `FrameLayout`?

If it was a single `Fragment` in the `Activity`, I would simply override `onCreateView()` which would receive the container `FrameLayout` as a parameter, and I would return the inflated layout of the `Fragment`.

But now that I have two `FrameLayout`s and two `Fragment`s to add in them, how would I tell the system which `FrameLayout` in the `Activity` I want to add my `Fragment` into?

Comment: post you code and what problem you are facing?

Comment: @perfection Some programming problems are in design, in deciding how a certain task is going to be achiever, not all problems are errors and stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do two `FragmentTransaction`'s like this in the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method of the `FragmentActivity`:

### Transaction 1

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.framelayout1, new Fragment1());
ft.commit();
```

### Transaction 2

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.framelayout2, new Fragment2());
ft.commit();
```

Comment: Even better is Shivams answer. But with `FragmentActivity` [Google docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) states: `When using this class as opposed to new platform's built-in fragment and loader support, you must use the getSupportFragmentManager() and getSupportLoaderManager() methods respectively to access those features.`

Comment: I am following a code sample, and they did something like `fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, searchResultsListFragment);`, where the only explanation of `android.R.id.content` I could find was that "it gives the root element of a view without the need to know its name/type/id" [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776768/android-what-is-android-r-id-content-used-for) - so I thought the first argument of `add()` had to be the root element in the `Fragment`'s layout. Let me try this one.

Comment: @Zarah from Google docs, the `add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment)` first parameter (`containerViewId`) has the following description: `Optional identifier of the container this fragment is to be placed in. If 0, it will not be placed in a container.` [Google doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add)

Comment: Yep. You should use `getSupportFragmentManager()` and `getSupportLoaderManager()` methods

Answer (score 1):

How about this ? :

```
SampleFragment1 fragment_1 = new SampleFragment1();
SampleFragment2 fragment_2 = new SampleFragment2();

FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.frameLayout1, fragment_1);
transaction.add(R.id.frameLayout2, fragment_2);
transaction.commit();
```