# Snackbar inside Recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My logic doesn't work only when there is not permission for Call, If i have provided permission it works perfectly fine.

I am trying to invoke Snackbar inside my recycler view, Reason being one of my button in recycler view has to invoke Call facility. Hence i am checking for **Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE** permission and displaying a snakbar if there is no permission provided. While invoking the below code

```
private void showSnackbar(MyViewHolder v , final int mainTextStringId, final int actionStringId,
                          View.OnClickListener listener) {
    Snackbar.make(v.snackBarLayout,
            context.getString(mainTextStringId),
            Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .setAction(context.getString(actionStringId), listener).show();
}
```

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No suitable parent found from the
>   given view. Please provide a valid view.

However i am trying to parse my Viewholder form

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
....
....
....
  showSnackbar(holder,R.string.permission_rationale, android.R.string.ok,
                                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View view) {
                                            // Request permission
                                            startCallPermissionRequest();
                                        }
                                    });
}
```

### Response to suggested duplicate

I don't think this is a duplicate question, I tried changing snackbar to findviewbyId, It is not able to fetch that view to display. view comes only from ViewHolder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No suitable parent found from the given view. Please provide a valid view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47666685/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-suitable-parent-found-from-the-given-view)

Answer (score 2):

You are putting holder as parent view for Snackbar

```
 showSnackbar(holder,R.string.permission_rationale, android.R.string.ok,
                                new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view) {
                                        // Request permission
                                        startCallPermissionRequest();
                                    }
                                });
```

Instead of **holder** you need object of parent view(LinearLayout /RelativeLayout or whatever you have given)inside xml connected with this adapter class

Answer (score 0):

Finally i was able to solve it, The issue was with getting the parent view i did this to make it work **view.getRootView()**

```
  private void showSnackbar(View v , final int mainTextStringId, final int actionStringId,
                              View.OnClickListener listener) {
        Snackbar.make(view.getRootView().findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                context.getString(mainTextStringId),
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction(context.getString(actionStringId), listener).show();
    }
```