# Android Snackbar: No suitable parent found from the given view. Please provide a valid view

Tags: java, android, android-snackbar

I have a Fragment class and a normal HelpFunctionsclass. I want the Fragment class to show a Snackbar by calling a method in the HelpFunctionsclass.

In the Fragment class I call the following code after a certain button has been pressed:

```
HelpFunctions.showSnackBar(getActivity(), getString(R.string.message_ratingSubmittedNotSuccessfully),  binding.getRoot());
```

And in the HelpFunctions class the method for displaying the Snackbar looks like this:

```
public static void showSnackBar(Activity activity, String message, View root){

    Snackbar currentSnackBar = Snackbar.make( root, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    View sbView = currentSnackBar.getView();
    sbView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.colorBlue));
    currentSnackBar.show();
}
```

When I execute my code I get the following error message "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No suitable parent found from the given view. Please provide a valid view.". I looked for a solution to this problem and found this answer: [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No suitable parent found from the given view. Please provide a valid view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47666685/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-suitable-parent-found-from-the-given-view). Here it is stated that I should use `findViewById(android.R.id.content)` for the root. Unfortunately, when I use this in my method `showSnackBar` in the line `Snackbar currentSnackBar = Snackbar.make( findViewById(android.R.id.content), message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);` I get the error message from the compiler "Cannot resolve method 'findViewById' in 'HelpFunctions'".

Any idea why I am getting this error message and why I can't change it with findViewById? How else can I show a Snackbar?

Comment: `findViewById()` is a method on `Activity` and `View`. Most likely, the `findViewById(android.R.id.content)` call is to be made on your `Activity`. What you really should be passing in is some child of a `CoordinatorLayout`. This is covered in [the documentation for `Snackbar.make()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/Snackbar?hl=en#make(android.view.View,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int)).

Comment: The solution may be to use
Snackbar.make(context, view, text, duration)
Because you are using it outside the View layer, you need to pass the context.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks for your answer. I tried to use `findViewById` in my Fragment class (which is a UI class) and there I get the same error. Further, in the documentation of Snackbar you see, that it expects a View. By using `binding.getRoot()` as an argument I pass a view to it as you can read in the official documentation of ViewBinding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding). So I don't understand why this error occurs with the Illegal Argument

Comment: @EmmanuelConradie: Thanks for your answer. The question is what is the context and how can I create and pass it? Furthermore, there is a constructor in SnackBar that does not need any context and I try to use this one with 3 arguments that I pass to it. Unforunately I still get the error message.

Comment: @VanessaF you already have the context, it is the activity you are passing

Comment: @EmmanuelConradie: What is then the view? I thought the activity is the view? Or shall it serve as both the view and the context?

Comment: @VanessaF Try the updated answer

Comment: @EmmanuelConradie: Does not work. Yields the same error.

Comment: @VanessaF could you please specify which line you are getting the error on?
Because I don't think the problem is the currentSnackbar. I think it is when you are trying to get the snackbar view

Comment: Have you made sure your root view has loaded correctly before passing it?

Comment: @EmmanuelConradie: How can I make sure that the root view has loaded correctly? I just use the following command `binding.getRoot()` and that should actually do it. What else can I do?

Comment: @VanessaF please post the code of how you are loading your view and where you are calling show snackbar

Comment: @EmmanuelConradie: Unforunately the code is quite long (more than 1000 lines). So I don't think it makes sense to post it. But do you know what I can do to ensure that the"root view has loaded correctly before passing it" as you wrote? The error comes from the line `Snackbar currentSnackBar = Snackbar.make( activity, root, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);`. I don't think that I need an activity here because on other occasions in the app I never use the activity and so far everything has been okay. Strangely in this case this IllegalArgumentException occurs and I don't know why. Any suggestions?

Comment: @VanessaF your first problem is that your view class is 1000 lines long. Your view should not contain any logic.
Call showSnackbar right after you called onBind(view)

Comment: @VanessaF I do not know in which method you are binding or inflating your view so without code I cannot help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246924/discussion-between-vanessaf-and-emmanuel-conradie).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation.

> Snackbar will try and find a parent view to hold Snackbar's view from the value given to view. Snackbar will walk up the view tree trying to find a suitable parent, which is defined as a CoordinatorLayout or the window decor's content view, whichever comes first.

You need to now provide context direct the view up the hierarchy

> Context: The context to use to create the Snackbar view.

Therefore use `Snackbar.make(Context context, View view, CharSequence text, int duration)`

Pass it like

```
public static void showSnackBar(Activity activity, String message, View root){
    Snackbar currentSnackBar = Snackbar.make( activity, root, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel for your answer. Unfortunately your suggested code leads to the same error message "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No suitable parent found from the given view. Please provide a valid view."

Comment: Hi, actually this line throws the error `Snackbar currentSnackBar = Snackbar.make( activity, root, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);`