# How can I create a Setting activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I created a Setting activity in my app, but it didn't work.
This is my `SettingFragment` class:

```
public class SettingFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat
{
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey)
    {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref, rootKey);
    }
}
```

This is my `SettingActivity`:

```
public class SettingActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content, new SettingFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

This is `MainActivity`. Clicking the button will open `SettingActivity`.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

And this is `Preference.xml`:

```
<PreferenceScreen 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Preference
        app:key="feedback"
        app:title="Send feedback"
        app:summary="Report technical issues or suggest new features"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

What is the `R.id.content`? It was used in the [developer.android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings) site example.
What is the problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: we will need a bit more of an error than "it didn't work" to determine the problem you are trying to solve. What error are you getting? To answer your question about `R` it is an autogenerated file that contains all your resource IDs.

Comment: What is not working? What kind of error are you getting? Also include the `activity_setting.xml` layout file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the R.id.content?

Lets assume that this is the `SettingActivity` layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SettingsActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The call to `replace` will swap your fragment with `R.id.content`. You can also call replace with `android.R.id.content`, read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776768/android-what-is-android-r-id-content-used-for).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `android.R.id.content`. This will replace the root content with the Fragment's content. you can find more information about `android.R.id.content` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776768/android-what-is-android-r-id-content-used-for)

```java
// Display the fragment as the main content.
getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingFragment())
                .commit();
```