# How do i assign view in onCreate method in an activity android

Tags: android, view

I am having the following method which passes View

```
private void doSomething(View view){ }
```

The problem am having is how do i call this view in onCreate method in an Activity, i will have to pass the view

For Example

```
View view;

doSomething(view)
```

How do is assign view/instantiate view, am using getView() but its not working

Like

```
view = getView()
```

For Example in fragments onViewCreatedMethod has an argument view which i can assign to the method when am calling it. Example below

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    doSomething(view);
}
```

Is it possible to do that inside onCreate method in fragment, can I parse the View arguments in onCreate method in activity

Comment: What view do you want to get ? the activity view (layout) ? a view inside the layout ?

Comment: Do You want to assign `view` with some View from Your layout?

Comment: Instead of using `getView()`, in the `onCreate` method you can just use `findViewById(R.id.xxx)`

Comment: @SebastienRieu i have edited the question to further explain

Comment: First, the right question to ask is "what do you need a view in a method of activity" ? (1) If you need to setup a specific view of your layout, for example TextView with id textView you can get this view doing "TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textView)" (2) If you needs the "activity" view, i suggest you to set an id to the activity layout parent view, and get it in the activity like this "View parent = findViewById(R.id.myActivityLayoutParentId)" and then pass this view to your doSomething method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your onCreate method, once you've called `setContentView`, you can use `findViewById` to get whatever View you want.  If you want the root view for some reason, you can pass [`android.R.id.content`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7776768/208273).

For example:

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Replace your_layout_id with your Activity layout ID
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_id);

    View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content);

    // Replace with whatever ID/View type you have in your code
    // Button and your_button_id are just examples
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.your_button_id); 
}
```