# How to put focus on particular EditText and display the softkey?

Tags: android, android-layout

When an Activity opens I need to set focus on one of two edit texts and automatically open the softkey pad so the user can just start typing. How can this be done?

Comment: I know its easier to click the minus button than answer but we need more constructive feedback.

Comment: Can someone else please + this so we don't get too negative!

Comment: If this is how you participate perhaps a SOCIAL network is not the right place.... I mean let us know what the pain point is.  I really see nothing wrong with the question.

Comment: Look below to see social collaboration in action.

Comment: Not sure how you get to the conclusion that [this is a social networking site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65261/is-stack-overflow-a-social-networking-site). What's wrong with this question? You don't show any research effort *(this has been answered often before)* or any attempt to solve this on your own. I guess if you don't do research on your problem, you won't check the meaning of downvotes either. See the downvote tooltip. And after you posted a lazy question, you complain that people pick the lazy option "downvote and move on"? I find that funny.

Comment: It might not be the definition of a social network, but the point is that is people centered to solve (technical) problems.

Comment: Maybe, that's kind of subjective. Anyway the other issues are still there, so when it comes to beeing social: If you do people a favor and write a good question, people are more likely to do you a favor and actually help you. Waste their time with stuff that can be googled and they react like this.

Comment: The waste of time is an illusion on your part.  No ones time is wasted but perhaps mine and others is saved.  An old answer to a question is not necessarily what people are looking for. Have you not heard of deprecation or backward compatibility issues.

Comment: deprecation you have probably heard of ...

Comment: Lovely. I'm completely sure that there are no compatibility issues in place and so on. Why did you even ask for an explanation when you didn't want to hear it anyway? I wonder why I even leave these comments - that was certainly a waste of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the xml for the layout, add `<requestFocus />` under the EditText you want focused.

Comment: Will this also cause the soft key to appear?

Comment: Not without a bit more code. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105354/how-to-show-soft-keyboard-when-edittext-is-focused