# EditText, focus, soft keyboard troubles

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

OK I have an array of EditTexts, and I want to loop through them, so if some EditText does not contain text, I want to ask user for input, and I'm through a lot of hours and a lot of reading but I can not understand how this is supposed do work. So few questions:

Is requestfocus() enough ? (It's not working - keyboard does not show)

I have tried with OnFocusChangeListener and than tried to Show keyboard (showSoftInput(view,InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)) if there is focus on editText again it is not working.

Does anyone know of any good example to get me out of this triangle?

Answer (score 1):

`view.requestFocus()` is not enough;

I'm using this code:

```
public static void setSoftwareKeyboardVisibility(Context context, View view, boolean value) {
        final InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (value) {
            view.requestFocus();
            manager.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        } else {
            // Any other not EditText View
            manager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN);
            view.requestFocus();
        }
    }
```

But You said that standatr method is not working. Try to call `showSoftInput` not in `OnFocusChange` method. Call it when you setting focus on EditText.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but still the focus is there on editText but the keyboard shows only after I touch the control :(

Comment: @AdnanPirota , hmmmm. Do you change `windowSoftInputMode` for your activity in manifest? And what is value?

Answer (score 0):

I can not find now the page where I got resolution to my problem, but the solution was as follows:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

With `editText.requestFocus()` where editText is your EditText View you focus the cursor to the field.

If you want to show the keyboard after focusing, look at the answer of raukodraug [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105354/how-to-show-soft-keyboard-when-edittext-is-focused).