# Select EditText programmatically in Android

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

I'm new in Android and I can't select an `EditText` programmatically.
My scenario.
I have a lot of `EditText`, but only one is enable, I'll calling it `A`. The user write in this `EditText` `A` with the keyboard; when he finishes writing, starts an algorithm that recognize the text inside `A` and put it in the right `EditText`, for example `B`. After this I need to empty `A` and set the focus on it, show the cursor inside `A` and show the keyboard.

I'll try with `myET.requestFocus()` but nothing happens.

How can I make `A` editable again without the user having to touch `A` ?

Thanks

Comment: Consider accepted answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105354/how-to-show-soft-keyboard-when-edittext-is-focused) question. Hope it's will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```java
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myET.requestFocus();
        }
    }, 100);
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to show the keyboard without pressing on the TextEdit, you must put the code inside a handler with some delay. It works well with 200ms delay, but failed without any delay or with only a delay of 1ms.

```
   (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            youEditText.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN , 0, 0, 0));
            youEditText.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP , 0, 0, 0));                       

        }
        }, 200);
```

And so by this code, you simulate a tap on the EditText.
Cheers