# How Show soft keyboard automatically when EditText receives focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I want show keyboard when my EditText receives focus. I tried many methods but nothing not helped.
I tried:
1.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

whith different flags.

2.`getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);`

3. `<requestFocus />`

4.

```
 editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    editText.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            editText.requestFocus();
```

4 method is fork but it bad solution. Thus it is written here [Show soft keyboard automatically when EditText receives focus](https://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/show-soft-keyboard-automatically-when-edittext-receives-focus/)

Before, I used the method 2 and it worked. but now no longer. and I created a blank Project and it does not work, none of the methods

UPDATE:

```
<style name="Theme.TransparencyDemo" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show soft-keyboard when edittext is focused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105354/how-to-show-soft-keyboard-when-edittext-is-focused)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add flags to your activity as well which will show the keyboard automatically

```
<activity name="package.ActivityName" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"/>
```

this is mostly useful if you expect the focus to be applied when the activity launches

Also you can use in **Fragment**:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

or in **Activity**

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Comment: @ip696 this is using different flags then you have

Comment: I tried all the flags but did not work. But now it worked! I'm in shock! as? thank!

Answer (score 1):

Use WindowManager instead of InputMehtodManager inside onFocusChange listener of edittext, As Its reliable.

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus) {
        dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    }
   } });
```

Comment: I can not understand why does not work the usual way, without listeners

Comment: @ip696 : Because may be you are using other components which get focused earlier than edittext. So its depends on hierarchy you have designed with your layout.

Comment: hierarchy ? you mean in order of XML? does it matter?

Comment: @ip696 : Yeah, I mean the layout design of XML, It matters.

Comment: New Projects (test) your method worked. but not in the working. I will deal with XML thank!

Comment: i copy layout from my project to test project and keyboard showed. But in the project do not show.

Comment: @ip696 : Make sure that there is no any depedancy on your activity code on which you are using that layout. And which theme are you applying to your activity?

Comment: I updated the question of added subject. what do you mean "depedancy on your activity"?

Comment: @ip696 : First can you confirm that your edittext setOnFocusChange listener is working or not? Keep log and try to check it first.

Comment: To be honest I do not understand you

Comment: @ip696 : Post your activity code that you have written