# How to enable keyboard in Android widget

Tags: android

in the xml file I wrote:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/tray_opener" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_box"
        android:layout_width="25sp"
        android:layout_height="25sp"
        android:inputType="textUri"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and in java main activity I wrote:

```
EditText msearchword = (EditText) mPlayerButtonsLayout.findViewById(R.id.search_box);
```

[Developed Application](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxJJna55vBwAME1xZ2g0QnQ4alE) Result is in the following link but the keyboard doesn't pops up.

Comment: try this  http://stackoverflow.com/a/31779598/4824159

Comment: I'm not sure what that video you linked to has anything to do with the keyboard