# Doesn't show Keyboard when requesting EditText after Dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-edittext, focus

I have a problem.

I made custom `Dialog`(loading spinner).
I touching down the `Button`. Then opens `RelativeLayout` with table and edit text which works like search.

My problem is that when i show loader between button touch and opening Layout it focuses on `EditText` but doesn't show keyboard. When i don't use my dialog, it works fine. I tried it on foreground and in thread - the same result.

**XML**:

```
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:indeterminateOnly="false"
            android:id="@+id/loader_spiner"

            android:background = "@xml/progress"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Code**:

```
 public void prepareLoader(){
        loader = new Dialog(context);
        loader.setContentView(R.layout.ag_loader);
        loader.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        spinerLoader = (ProgressBar) loader.findViewById(R.id.loader_spiner);
    }

    public void showLoader(){

        spinerLoader.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.xml.splash_spinner));
        loader.show();
    }

    public static void hideLoader(){

        loader.hide();

    }
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you checked this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105354/how-to-show-soft-keyboard-when-edittext-is-focused

Comment: Please follow above link .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in 'loader.show()' you can try this code to show keyboard:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

or:

```
loader.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

or:

```
loader.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

or if not work again try it:

```
Handler delayedRun = new Handler();
delayedRun.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    youreditText.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.showSoftInput(youreditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with getting some time for keyboard to appear.

```
new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
    new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (thisSearchable) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.showSoftInput(searchInput, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
            }
        }
    }, 300);
```