# Android : softkeyboard does not consume input event / touch

Tags: android, keyboard, landscape, android-input-method

I am working on an app which is in landscape mode.

When I open default keyboard programmatically it does not consume any input events in landscape mode (opens keyboard but does not show any preview of keyboard click). But if I open default keyboard in portrait it opens keyboard & shows the preview of a key on which I click i.e it works as expected in portrait mode.

**I don't know why it is not accepting inputs in landscape mode.**

Here is how I am opening the keyboard.

```
final InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Also, if I specify flags called **InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT** it does not even show the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Read this:

[How to show soft-keyboard when edittext is focused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105354/how-to-show-soft-keyboard-when-edittext-is-focused)

```
EditText yourEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

And remember to put

```
<activity
[...]
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
[...]
>
```

in your manifest

Answer (score 0):

I had exact the same issue in combination with a custom View.

To fix this problem I needed to implement onCreateInputConnection in the custom view to set the InputType to TYPE_CLASS_TEXT.

If you need to capture onKeyDown and onKeyUp events for the backspace key you can use TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL.

Here an example:

```
/**
 * needed make softkeyboard work in landscape mode and to capture backspace.
 */
@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs){
    outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL;
    outAttrs.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NONE | EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_FULLSCREEN;
    return null;
}
```