# softkeyboard cant remain open when moves to next edit field in andorid

Tags: android

when i move from one `EditText` to next `EditText` through next button on softkeyboard , softkeyboard cant open until or unless i have to touch the edit text. WHAT I WANT : when user click the next button which is on softkeyboard , on next edittext the softkeyboard will appear...
The code which i am currently using

```
 etRegisterLName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            //if (!(hasFocus)) {
               // code to execute when EditText loses focus
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "focus method", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //etRegisterLName.requestFocus();
            //}
        }
    });
```

my manifest of this activity

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.ukcl.driverapp.RegisterActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"

        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible|stateHidden" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: check the below soluton and let me know in case of concer

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha okay , let me check

Comment: can you post your xml file code

Comment: why you doing state hidden just put android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible|stateVisible" both.

Comment: on second edit text move keyboard will remain shown on screen you not need to touch edittext.

Comment: yeah , i know,, but without touching can it appear when i pressed the next button ??

Comment: it will remains appear on next move give it a try bro . .

Comment: @jaydroider can u explain it with code ?

Comment: just change it in your manifest and i think it will work. remove state hidden and add this android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible|stateVisible".

Comment: @jaydroider its not working , i checked it

Comment: Refer to the following link on stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105354/how-to-show-soft-keyboard-when-edittext-is-focused Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Define cursorVisible property in your edit text like this.

```
<EditText                
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:imeOptions="actionNext"
  android:cursorVisible="true"/>
```

Comment: Means your editext is dismissed afetr clicking on the next button of the softkeyboard???

Comment: no , my keyboard is not appearing on the next edit field when i click through next buton

Comment: @ArslanAliAwan..plz remove the android:windowSoftInputMode from the manifest file and than check and let me know

Comment: Ravindra Kushwaha i rremove the android:windowSoftInputMode from the manifest file even then its not working