# Opening keyboard from android web-site

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-softkeyboard

I'm making a website for Android devices and I'd like the keyboard to pop up automatically.
I have a javascript that focuses on a text field and I see the cursor but the keyboard doesn't pop up until I tap the screen.

Is there a way to make it work from the html/JS?

Comment: You should take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403632/android-show-soft-keyboard-automatically-when-focus-is-on-an-edittext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// create dialog
final AlertDialog dialog = ...; 

// request keyboard   
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode (WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

This works for me.