# Barcode scanner bluetooth device disables the keyboard

Tags: android

I have connected a barcode scanner to my android phone via Bluetooth. unfortunately, this disables my original keyboard, so I can't type anything. It seems android identify the new device as a keyboard. Any workaround?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable both hardware and virtual keyboards on Android ice cream sandwich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561760/how-to-enable-both-hardware-and-virtual-keyboards-on-android-ice-cream-sandwich)

Comment: Best answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24287780/44816