# Trying to use external bluetooth barcode scanner and soft keyboard

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm trying to use an external bluetooth scanner and the soft keyboard for my app, but when I connect the bluetooth scanner, Android treats the scanner as an input device and does not let me use the soft keyboard for edit texts. I have tried:
[Show soft keyboard even though a hardware keyboard is connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602209/show-soft-keyboard-even-though-a-hardware-keyboard-is-connected)

I tried creating a class that extends `InputMethodService` and did a method override on `onEvaluateInputViewShown()`, but `onEvaluateInputViewShown()` is never called. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you find any solution?