# Force soft keyboard to be displayed even when hardware keyboard is present

Tags: react-native

I'm creating an app using react-native, the soft keyboard gets suppressed when there's a hardware keyboard connected. I need it to be shown.
I'm essentially asking the same question as here:[Show soft keyboard even though a hardware keyboard is connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602209/show-soft-keyboard-even-though-a-hardware-keyboard-is-connected) but specifically for react native.

Answer (score 0):

You mean an external keyboard for your tablet?
You can try to set the keyboard type to 'null'.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to add the `onPress="blur()"` prop in your `Input`/`TextInput`