How can I display the virtual keyboard when I have a physical keyboard (Barcode Reader) connected to my device in my app .NET MAUI 8.0?
I am developing an application in .NET MAUI 8.0 where I have a barcode reader connected to it via bluetooth. However, this reader when connected works like a physical keyboard, and on some screens I need the virtual keyboard because the user, in addition to scanning the barcodes, can type the name of the products to search.
The problem is that I cannot display the virtual keyboard if I am connected to the barcode reader because the device understands that it already has a physical keyboard connected to it.
I've already tried KeyboardExtensions.ShowKeyboardAsync(entrytest, default), but it doesn't display the virtual keyboard either. I've tried and looked for everything, but I haven't been able to get anywhere.

Android, iOS, or Windows?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@StephenQuan my app is only for android

Because it's Android specific, perhaps some Android specific code can be added? Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/platform-specifics/soft-keyboard-input-mode?view=net-maui-8.0 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602209/show-soft-keyboard-even-though-a-hardware-keyboard-is-connected
