# android how to show virtual keyboard when pop up a custom dialog

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: show soft keyboard automatically when focus is on an EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403632/android-show-soft-keyboard-automatically-when-focus-is-on-an-edittext)

I want to show the soft keyboard when my dialog pop up to enter the text immediately? (I use android 2.3.3)
I have searched. But all solutions I found not work? Help me!!!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have custom dialog, so you can set editText to request focus... So it'll show up keyboard:

```
<EditText
  ...  >
     <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```