# How can I force the Android keyboard to pop up?

Tags: java, android, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: show soft keyboard automatically when focus is on an EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403632/android-show-soft-keyboard-automatically-when-focus-is-on-an-edittext)

I'm writing an app and one of the main things I need is to for the keyboard open and able to type on the text field thats in focus.

I've tried:

```
((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

This does not work, can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Have you tried this solution? 
 http://stackoverflow.com/a/2418314/1489493

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add follows to your activity in AndroidMainifest.xml:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
```

and then may look like that

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible">
</activity>
```