# showing softkeyboard in android

Tags: android, show, show-hide

I want to open the soft keyboard in android automatically after opening  the activity . I used the code mentioned here 
[Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)
but it doesn't work.
This is my code.

```
final EditText txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxt_hidenprac);
txtName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        txtName.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) Practice.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.showSoftInput(txtName, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
            }
        });
    }
});
txtName.requestFocus();




<activity
    android:name="com.example.moisun01.Practice"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible">
</activity>
```

***I found it why it doesn't work*** . its because my layout is in **landscape** orientation.
and in **portrate** orientation it works fine.
but my App is in landscape . **is there any solution for this problem?**

Comment: add in manifest for that activity: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work yet

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: show soft keyboard automatically when focus is on an EditText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403632/android-show-soft-keyboard-automatically-when-focus-is-on-an-edittext)

Comment: Test in the real device .it will work.

Comment: I'm testing in on real device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer is already given in comment box... it worked for me..
You dont need to do too much...just Add

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
```

in your activity tag in manifest file
In this way soft keyboard in android automatically opens as activity start

..if this wasn't happening to you..
then..try to give focus to first edittext usin requestFocus() method

Answer (score 0):

In the Activiy onCreate() you can write like this.
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(mEditText, 0);

or ,in the Manifest file you can use
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" under activity.

Comment: InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
 imm.showSoftInput(etxt_practice,InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);

Answer (score 0):

(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); imm.showSoftInput(mEditText, 0);

or ,in the Manifest file you can use android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" under activity.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

onCreate method

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```