# ANDROID: Getting key presses from Android soft keyboard

Tags: java, android

Wanting to know how to get the Android soft keyboard to open up without having to enter something into a field and how to get the key presses from the open keyboard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kai -

To show the keyboard you can use the below code:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
```

(as provided here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11155404)

To get the key presses without an input field focused, you can use the onKeyDown event handler like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    // Capture keyCodes here

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
}
```